# How to create cab file from mshc?

Tags: msbuild, cab, msbuild-4.0

I am using following task to create cab file.

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(CabCreatorPath)\CABARC.exe&quot; n &quot;@(CabFile)&quot; &quot;$(DynamicViewDrive)\Source\Output\ClassReference.mshc&quot;  "/>
```

Is there any other alternative way is there to create cab file from mshc?

Answer (score 1):

You could [write your own task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9883dzc.aspx) to simplify the syntax.

Usage would then instead be something like:

```
<MshcCab nflag="true" Input="@(CabFile)" Output="$(DynamicViewDrive)\Source\Output\ClassReference.mshc" />
```